# Why isn't Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL centering view vertically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a `View` in the center (vertically) of its parent `View`, which is a `RelativeLayout`.

I tried `View.setGravity(Gravity.VERTICAL);`

but it doesn't work perfectly, the position of the view is slightly below the center. There must be something wrong with my codes, but I can't seem to spot the bug that is preventing the view from being at the center.

```
        ....

        initArrayViews[a] = new RelativeLayout(context);
        initArrayViews[a].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        initArrayViews[a].setLayoutParams(screensize);

        inInit.addView(initArrayViews[a]);

         RelativeLayout theone = new RelativeLayout(context);
         theone.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer1);
         theone.setLayoutParams(screensize);
         initArrayViews[a].addView(theone);
         theone.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
         params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

         LinearLayout X = new LinearLayout(context);
         X.setLayoutParams(params);
         X.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundr);
         X.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         theone.addView(X);
```

Comment: What `View` exactly are you trying to center? What kind of `View` is it?